# Add text in a photo (eclipse)

Tags: android, gallery, photo

I wanted to know if there is an example of an application to add text in a photo gallery that is loaded from the phone. After you save the edited photo. Thanks

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you are asking. Are you asking about adding text to an image like a watermark or something else?

Comment: Yes, you can achieve that in many ways. just google it

Comment: add text to a photo that is present in the gallery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try [this](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/23/image-processing-watermarking-on-the-fly/):

```
public static Bitmap mark(Bitmap src, String watermark, Point location, Color color, int alpha, int size, boolean underline) {
int w = src.getWidth();
int h = src.getHeight();
Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, src.getConfig());

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);

Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(color);
paint.setAlpha(alpha);
paint.setTextSize(size);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setUnderlineText(underline);
canvas.drawText(watermark, location.x, location.y, paint);

return result;
}
```